# Chrome: Where are the console log messages?

Tags: google-chrome

Sorry for the elementary question, but I couldn't find the answer in Google. How can I check the messages in Chrome Console? Is anything is misconfigured in Chrome? Please take a look at the screenshot.

[image: Chrome dev panel]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are filtering the messages in the console.
Remove whatever you have written as /html/body/...... and you should be able to see the logs

Comment: Thanks! It works. I don't know how filtering input box was filled automatically.